# Tooltip for not a link could be obscured in mobile web

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, uploader

If you type not a link text into “link from the web” field of the image upload page in mobile web then you could see something white and weird in the center:

> [image: White and weird]

After splitting the keyboard you could see that this is a tooltip:

> [image: Enter a URL]

I’m not sure whether this is a site or a browser/OS issue. Let the developers decide. I would like to see that tooltip in the visible area without a need to split a keyboard.

Tested on iPad in Chrome/Firefox/Safari.

Comment: This doesn't affect Android Firefox, must be specific to iPad. I see this message: "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported" when I type "not_an_link" and submit it. It appears in red just above the keyboard.